# Intermittent jQuery failure in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm seeing a strange issue (only in production of course) where some $.post requests are failing intermittently with the error:

`{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

I've looked into this and in most cases there seem to be two possible issues:

1) *Cross domain errors.* This shouldn't be an issue since the chrome extension is set up to be able to access the domain, additionally since it only fails sometimes this seems like it shouldn't be the issue

2) *not calling e.preventDefault()*. The request is being made from the background process so i don't think this is the issue. Again the fact that it is intermittent makes this unlikely.

Additionally it seems *UNLIKELY* that its purely network related since the only way we know about these issues are posting to an endpoint on our server to retrieve the errors...i.e. if the computer was offline, the request sent in the failblock should fail as well.

Are there any other known issues that could cause the query to fail with that error?

UPDATE
Here's some pseudo code for the way the request is made:

```
$.post(this._baseUrl  + "/my_endpoint", JSON.stringify(data))
  .done(function(res){
    //SUCCESS!
  })
  .fail(function(error, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: This sounds like a case where the request did not complete successfully as opposed to have an error in response (e.g. DNS issues, timeouts, etc.) - so it may simply be network conditions.

Comment: is there any way to determine the real cause? i.e. jquery is supposed to say the statusText should be "timeout" in the case of a network timeout

Comment: Please add a minimal example of your request code that would log the error you show.

Comment: Are you seeing any issues on the server-side of things?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst no issues server side, everything is returning 200s (when it makes it to the server) but from what i've read about this error its caused when the request is cancelled client side.

Comment: It could be a bug in this specific version of jQuery. Try another version. Or use XMLHttpRequest directly to ensure no wrapper is causing the issue.

Comment: The code you added would not _log_ that value. How are you getting that object? The first argument to `fail` callback is _not_ the error but the request object itself. Have you logged the other two?